# glmnet: at what lambda is each coefficient shrunk to 0?

Tags: r, regression, glmnet, lasso-regression

I am using LASSO (from package **glmnet**) to select variables. I have fitted a `glmnet` model and plotted coefficients against lambda's.

```
library(glmnet)
set.seed(47)
x = matrix(rnorm(100 * 3), 100, 3)
y = rnorm(100)
fit = glmnet(x, y)
plot(fit, xvar = "lambda", label = TRUE)
```

[image: plot]

Now I want to get the order in which coefficients become 0. In other words, at what lambda does each coefficient become 0?

I don't find a function in **glmnet** to extract such result. How can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `glmnetPath` in my initial answer is now in an **R** package called **solzy**.

```
## you may need to first install package "remotes" from CRAN
remotes::install_github("ZheyuanLi/solzy")

## Zheyuan Li's R functions on Stack Overflow
library(solzy)

## use function `glmnetPath` for your example
glmnetPath(fit)

#$enter
#  i  j ord var     lambda
#1 3  2   1  V3 0.15604809
#2 2 19   2  V2 0.03209148
#3 1 24   3  V1 0.02015439
#
#$leave
#  i  j ord var     lambda
#1 1 23   1  V1 0.02211941
#2 2 18   2  V2 0.03522036
#3 3  1   3  V3 0.17126258
#
#$ignored
#[1] i   var
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

**Interpretation of `enter`**

As `lambda` decreases, variables (see `i` for numeric ID and `var` for variable names) enter the model in turn (see `ord` for the order). The corresponding `lambda` for the event is `fit$lambda[j]`.

- variable 3 enters the model at lambda = 0.15604809, the 2nd value in `fit$lambda`;
- variable 2 enters the model at lambda = 0.03209148, the 19th value in `fit$lambda`;
- variable 1 enters the model at lambda = 0.02015439, the 24th value in `fit$lambda`.

**Interpretation of `leave`**

As `lambda` increases, variables (see `i` for numeric ID and `var` for variable names) leave the model in turn (see `ord` for the order). The corresponding `lambda` for the event is `fit$lambda[j]`.

- variable 1 leaves the model at lambda = 0.02211941, the 23rd value in `fit$lambda`;
- variable 2 leaves the model at lambda = 0.03522036, the 18th value in `fit$lambda`;
- variable 3 leaves the model at lambda = 0.17126258, the 1st value in `fit$lambda`.

**Interpretation of `ignored`**

If not an empty data.frame, it lists variables that never enter the model. That is, they are effectively ignored. (Yes, this can happen!)

**Note:** `fit$lambda` is decreasing, so `j` is in ascending order in `enter` but in descending order in `leave`.

---

To further explain indices `i` and `j`, take variable 2 as an example. It leaves the model (i.e., its coefficient becomes 0) at `j` = 18 and enters the model (i.e., its coefficient becomes non-zero) at `j` = 19. You can verify this:

```
fit$beta[2, 1:18]
## all zeros

fit$beta[2, 19:ncol(fit$beta)]
## all non-zeros
```

See [Obtain variable selection order from glmnet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73328900/4891738) for a more complicated example.